# localStorage not working in react js chrome

Tags: javascript, reactjs

New to React.js

I am running a simple function in react from a class that is not exporting a react component.

The function calls localStorage.setItem() to save results from a successful authentication process.

```
localStorage.setItem('access_token', authResult.accessToken);
localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);
localStorage.setItem('expires_at', expiresAt);
```

The code gets executed, but it does not save these values in localStorage, or anywhere else.

has anyone else experienced this?

Callback.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import LoaderAnimation from './LoaderAnimation';
import Auth from '../services/auth';

class Callback extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        auth: new Auth()
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.state.auth.handleAuthentication();
    this.props.history.push('/home')
}

render() {
    return(
        <LoaderAnimation />
    );
}
}

export default Callback;
```

auth.js

```
    handleAuthentication() {
this.auth0.parseHash((err, authResult) => {
  if (authResult && authResult.accessToken && authResult.idToken) {
    this.setSession(authResult);
  } else if (err) {
    history.replace('/');
    console.log(err);
  }
});
 }

setSession(authResult) {
// Set the time that the Access Token will expire at
let expiresAt = JSON.stringify((authResult.expiresIn * 1000) + new Date().getTime());
localStorage.setItem('access_token', authResult.accessToken);
localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);
localStorage.setItem('expires_at', expiresAt);
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the actual localStorage to see if anything is going on? Is anything coming up in the console? Are you sure that that code is actually running? Do you have a working example?

Comment: Are you sure that you are getting `authResult.accessToken`, `authResult.idToken` and `expiresAt`?

Comment: What browser are you testing the localStorage functionality in? Can you set localStorage values at all, even manually?

Comment: I think you just need to debug your code properly and a further `else` block to that `parseHash` callback...there's a chance the other conditions are not met

Comment: Ive just added a console.log(authResult) under the setSession function call and I authResult was present on the console but it was not present in the localStorage,

Comment: @GabeCoach can you confirm that the component is not unmounted before `handleAuthentication` completes?

Comment: @Leo Thanks for that. I am unsure how to find that out in React. I tried putting the function in componentWillUnmount but no luck there as well